# Flutter provider consumer removes my items

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a sort function in order to sort JSON data.
For this, I have a button that opens a "showModalBottomSheet".

Within it I can choose the following data of the school class numbers.
So in my data I have 6 classrooms when loading in my constructor.

My filter is represented by buttons which are active or not if the filter contains the number of the classroom. My code works pretty much, my problem is that when I select a filter button in order to activate or not the filter, the button is deleted instead of staying but changing color

**My notifier :**

```
class TablesNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  // Services
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  final jsonSelectorService = locator<JsonSelectorService>();

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //all data from my classerooms in JSON
  List<ClassroomModel> classrooms;
  // Data that I will display and reconstruct based on my filter parameters
  List<ClassroomModel> classroomsFiltered; 
  List<int> numberOfClassrooms = List(); 
  // Model which will store the parameters of my filters and as a function I will load the data to display
  FilterClassroomsModel filterClassroomsModel = FilterClassroomsModel();

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TablesNotifier(){
    _initialise();
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise() async{
    classrooms = await jsonSelectorService.classrooms('data');
    classroomsFiltered = classrooms ;

    // I install the number of existing classrooms
    // Here the result is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    classrooms.forEach((element) {
      if(!numberOfClassrooms.contains(element.type)){
        numberOfClassrooms.add(element.type);
      }
    });

    // I install the number of classrooms activated by default in my filter
    // As I decide to display all my classrooms by default
    // My filter on the classrooms must contain all the loaded classrooms
    filterClassroomsModel.classrooms = numberOfClassrooms;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Functions public
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void saveClassroomsSelected(int index)
  {
    // Here my classroom model also contains the numbers of the classrooms that I want to filter
    if(filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.contains(index)){
      filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.remove(index);
    }else{
      filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.add(index);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I have identified that in my function initialize () if I change my code by this it works :

```
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms= numberOfClassrooms; // this
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms= [1,2,3,4,5,6]; // By this
```

**I am losing the dynamic side of my classroom calculation and that does not suit me. But I don't understand this behavior.**

**My view :**

```
class TableScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  TableScreen({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: MenuDrawerComponent.builder(context),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundDark,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
        label: Text('Filter'),
        onPressed: () async{
          slideSheet(context);
        },
        backgroundColor: AppColors.contrastPrimary,
      ),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context)
  {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);

    if(_tableProvider.chargesFiltered == null){
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.colorShadowLight,
        ),
      );
    }else{
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right : 20, left : 20),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _tableProvider.classroomsFiltered.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                            // Some classrooms data
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  void slideSheet(BuildContext context) {
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context, listen:false);

    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return Wrap(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color(0xFF737373),
                child: Container(                 
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Some filters ...
                      // Here I want to rebuild the list of button for show the changes
                      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: _tableProvider,
                        child: Consumer<TablesNotifier>(
                            builder: (context, model, child){
                              return _listOfClassrooms(context);
                            }
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _listOfClassrooms(BuildContext context){
    var _tableProvider = Provider.of<TablesNotifier>(context);

    List<Widget> list = List<Widget>();
    var listClassrooms = _tableProvider.numberOfClassrooms;
    var filterClassrooms = _tableProvider.filterClassroomsModel.classrooms;

    for (var i = 0; i < listClassrooms.length; i++) {
      int selectIndex = 0;
      if(filterClassrooms.contains(listClassrooms[i])){
        selectIndex = listClassrooms[i];
      }

      list.add(
        RadioComponent(
            text: "${listClassrooms[i]}",
            index: listClassrooms[i],
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 56) /3,
            selectedIndex: selectIndex,
            onPressed: _tableProvider.saveChargesSelected,
          ),
      );
    }
    return Wrap(
        spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
        runSpacing: 8.0, // gap between lines
        children: list
    );
  }
}
```

**My FilterClassroomsModel :**

```
class FilterClassroomsModel {
  int order;
  int sort;
  List<int> classrooms;

  FilterClassroomsModel ({
    this.order = 0,
    this.sort = 0,
    this.classrooms = const[], 
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ '
        '${this.order}, '
        '${this.sort}, '
        '${this.classrooms}, '
        '}';
  }
}
```

EDIT : Resolved topic. Thanks to Javachipper.
In the notifier I replace that :

```
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms = numberOfClassrooms;
```

By that :

```
filter.classrooms = List<int>();
filter.classrooms.addAll(numberOfClassrooms);
```

Comment: you said that referencing numberOfClassrooms does not work but [1,2,3,4,5,6] works, right? i don't know much about flutter but can you maybe try debugging/logging the "numberOfClassrooms" list to see if it's correctly populated?

Comment: During initialization the variable "number Of Classrooms" is correctly filled.
It is during the reconstruction with provider that this variable changes but I do not understand why. If I enter the value of the classes in list directly as it is not a named variable, it is not changed afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms = numberOfClassrooms;
```

to:

```
 filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.addAll(numberOfClassrooms);
```

Update (you can also do it like this):

```
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms= new List<int>(); 
filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.addAll(numberOfClassrooms);
```

Comment: It doesn't work I have this error:
"Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list".
I edit my post by adding my model.
I spent the evening on it I don't understand why my "numberOfClassrooms" variable is modified if I modify the "filterClassroomsModel" variable...

Comment: its because of this filterClassroomsModel.classrooms = numberOfClassrooms;

Comment: update it to this:

FilterClassroomsModel ({
    this.order = 0,
    this.sort = 0,
    this.classrooms = [], 
  });

Comment: I do not understand why put this? My filterClassroomsModel is initialized in the variable part of my notifier: "FilterClassroomsModel filterClassroomsModel = FilterClassroomsModel ();". Precisely when I initialize it in the constructor, I want by default the empty list of my model (filterClassroomsModel.classrooms) to be replaced by the list of available classrooms provided by "numberOfClassrooms".

Comment: This works at initialization but does not work afterwards when I update the list of filterClassroomsModel which should contain only the classroom numbers that I want to have for the filter. If I remove number 3 in the list for example then my numberOfClassrooms is also changed and I don't understand why. This has the effect of making the number 3 button disappear.

Comment: I meant remove your const in the model. Then change your initialization to this:  filterClassroomsModel.classrooms.addAll(numberOfClassrooms);

Comment: It disappears because it has been removed in the list. It acts like a pointer, so your option is to add the values on it. You can also do it through foreach, that would mean your next challenge is that your classrooms is set to const which removing it should solve the problem. I updated my answer above. which would overwrite your set as a const default when there are no values passed on the constructor

Comment: Thank you I have the impression to advance. This creates another problem for me which comes from my "saveClassroomsSelected" function in my notifier.
The error: "The following RangeError was thrown building Consumer (dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope]):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5 "

Comment: Thank you for yoir help @javachipper. I appreciate ! I update the correction in the subject ;)